# How to add a group with long name to local group from command prompt or batch file?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, active-directory

When trying to add a global group with a name longer than 20 characters using `net.exe` I get an error saying that the syntax is incorrect, as follows:

```
C:\>NET.EXE localgroup MyRemoteUsers "really-long-group-name-here" /ADD

The syntax of this command is:

NET LOCALGROUP [groupname [/COMMENT:"text"]] [/DOMAIN]
groupname {/ADD [/COMMENT:"text"] | /DELETE}  [/DOMAIN]
groupname name [...] {/ADD | /DELETE} [/DOMAIN]
```

This problem is [documented by Microsoft here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324639).  I need this to work inside a standard .cmd batch file.  Is there a simple workaround?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use powershell in a batch file like this:

```
powershell -command "& { ([adsi]'WinNT://./your-local-group,group').Add('WinNT://YOURDOMAIN/your-really-long-global-group-name,group'); }"
```

One of the tricks above is to use double quotes for entire command while using single quotes within the commands.  This allows you to run the statement from `cmd.exe` or inside a .bat/.cmd file.